# Diagonalization of Hermitian matrices vs Unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lapack, complexity

What are the general algorithms used for diagonalization of large Hermitian matrices and Unitary matrices? ($>5000 \times 5000$)

LAPACK seems to diagonalize Hermitian matrices almost 20 times as fast as unitary matrices, and as far as I know, the routines are also different. How is the computational complexity calculated in each case?

If there is a review article which answers my questions please point me in that direction.

Comment: The one who downvoted me, please help me out to find a proper forum to ask this question. I really need a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LAPACK doesn't have a specialized routine for computing the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix, so you'd have to use a general-purpose eigenvalue routine for complex non-hermitian matrices.  This is slower than using a routine for the eigenvalues of a complex hermitian matrix, although I'm surprised that you're seeing a factor of 20 difference in run times.

However, there are algorithms that have been developed for the efficient computation of the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix.  See for example:

Gragg, William B. "The QR algorithm for unitary Hessenberg matrices." Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics 16, no. 1 (1986): 1-8.

David, Roden JA, and David S. Watkins. "Efficient implementation of the multishift QR algorithm for the unitary eigenvalue problem." SIAM journal on matrix analysis and applications 28, no. 3 (2006): 623-633.

Comment: Thank you for the references, I shall check them out. Yes I know I have to use the diagonalization for general purpose matrices for LAPACK. Barring the official documentation of LAPACK which I am sure is there somewhere, are there any references which discuss the routines in a verbose manner?

Comment: The LAPACK user's guide is online at: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/lapack_lug.html

Comment: Actually reading the documentation, I think what was happening is it was using the RRR method for the hermitian matrix which gave a huge speedup. I was using Mathematica so while I know they are using LAPACK, I did not know what particular algorithm they were using. Thank you for the help.